# How to keep remote config fetch time 15 minutes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

How to keep remote config fetch time 15 minutes? is the fetch parameter value is in milliseconds or seconds? In short what number should i pass
in fetch() method so that cache expires every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

try this code below,

```
long cacheExpiration = 900; // 15 minutes
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
            }
        }
    });
```